# $\mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})$ homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual group operation
$$(m,n)+(m',n')=(m+m',n+n').$$
I already showed that $\phi_{m,n}(x,y):=(x+m,y+n)$ defines an action of $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, namely
$$\phi_{p,q}(\phi{m,n}(x,y))=\phi_{p,q}(x+m,y+n)=(x+m+p,y+n+q)=\phi_{m+p,n+q}.$$
Right?

Now I have to show that $\mathbb{R}^2/\Gamma$ is homeomorphic to the torus. My definition of the torus is $S^1\times S^1$ and I already did prove once that this is homeomorphic to the parametrization given below. This is my attempt, but I'm not sure this is totally correct. Who can give me tips to prove it correctly?

**My attempt**

Use the following corollary:

*Assume that $(Y,\pi)$ is a quotient of the topological space $X$ modulo $R$. Then, for any topological space $Z$, there is a 1-1 correspondence between continuous maps $f: Y\rightarrow Z$ and continuous maps $\tilde{f}:X\rightarrow Z$ such that $\tilde{f}(x)=\tilde{f}(x')$ whenever $(x,x')\in R$. This correspondence is characterized by $\tilde{f}=f\circ \pi$.*

Using this we can see that the map $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S^1\times S^1, (a,b)\mapsto (R+r\cos(a))\cos(b),(R+r\cos(a))\sin(b), r\sin(a))$ with $a,b\in[0,2\pi]$ induces a continuous bijection $f: \mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow S^1\times S^1$. Now use the fact that $\tilde{f}$ is an open map (but I really do not know how to prove this, please help me with this!), and then we can conclude $f$ is a homeomorphism (continuous, bijection, inverse is continuous).

So, what I ask you is the following: Is my proof correct? And how do I prove $f$ is an open map?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to be able to apply the property of the quotient topology directly without any further arguments, then you need to define your map for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, not $a, b \in [0,2\pi]$. Also, what is this business with $R$ and $r$? If the torus is defined as $S^1 \times S^1$, then you don't need to fool with embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is what it looks like you're doing.

Comment: @David I'm not sure what you mean.. Why do I need to define my map for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$? And about the embedding, how can I define the map more easily?

Comment: Your property on the quotient topology $X/R$ is applicable when you have a function defined on $X$, not on a subset of $X$. You've defined your mapping on $[0,2\pi]^2$ rather than on the full set $\mathbb{R}^2$. For your other question, use $(s,t) \mapsto (e^{2\pi i s}, e^{2\pi i t})$.

Comment: @David Thank you! So when I add your comments then my proof is correct? And can you tell me how to prove $f$ is an open map?

Comment: It's not difficult to see that the resulting map from the quotient is bijective. You still need to show that it's open. You may have some theorems on topological groups that will help you with that. If you have to do it from scratch, let $U$ be open in the quotient group. Then the image of $U$ under $f$ is also the image of $\pi^{-1}(U)$ under $\tilde{f}$. Show that that image is open.

Answer (score 2):

Modulo showing $\tilde{f}$ is open and the minor corrections given by David in the comments, your proof looks good to me.  You could prove that $\tilde{f}$ is open, but in this case there's actually a trick that gives you that $f^{-1}$ is continuous for free without having to think about $\tilde{f}$.  Namely, if you can show that $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ is compact, then $f$ is a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, so it is automatically a homeomorphism.  And to show that $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ is compact, you can just note that it is the continuous image of the compact space $[0,2\pi]^2$ under the continuous map $\pi$.

Comment: ooh ofcourse, thanks!!