# What is the name of the following Corollary and theorem?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I was reading one of the answer on MSE: [$\mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})$ homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610477/mathbbr2-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-homeomorphic-to-s1-times-s1?rq=1)

One corollary used is 
*Assume that $(Y,\pi)$ is a quotient of the topological space $X$ modulo $R$. Then, for any topological space $Z$, there is a 1-1 correspondence between continuous maps $f: Y\rightarrow Z$ and continuous maps $\tilde{f}:X\rightarrow Z$ such that $\tilde{f}(x)=\tilde{f}(x')$ whenever $(x,x')\in R$. This correspondence is characterized by $\tilde{f}=f\circ \pi$.*

And a theorem is used:
Let X and Y be topological spaces and let f:X→Y. If X is compact, Y is Hausdorff, and f is a continuous bijection, then f is a homeomorphism between X and Y.

http://mathonline.wikidot.com/homeomorphisms-between-compact-and-hausdorff-spaces

I wonder what is the source of the corollary and theorem, and I wonder if the corollary and theorem have a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your corollary (if I understand you correctly) sounds like „passing to the quotient.“ You could look this up for example in Lee‘s Introduction to Topological Manifols.

Your theorem is a consequence of the „closed map lemma“, which states that a continuous map from a compact space into a Hausdorff space is closed.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind to tell me which chapter of Lee's book I should be reading?

Comment: In chapter 3 the section „characteristic property of the quotient topology“ p.72 and chapter 4 the section „the closed map lemma“ p.100 in the second edition of the book.